# how to use spark in netbeans

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to spark and I just want to use some functions in spark.I have already download spark jar files and add it as external library. I need to import following class:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.AssociationRules;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowthModel;
```

But I got error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - package org.apache.spark.api.java does not exist
```

I am confused and search relevant explanation. Some of them say it is used with Maven. So I am confused because I just want to use several method inside the spark library. Could anyone help me with that?